# Kubernetes dynamic configuration of CPU resource limit

Tags: kubernetes, linux-kernel, cpu-usage

Kubernetes CPU manager provides a way to configure CPU resource limit [statically](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/cpu-management-policies/#cpu-management-policies). However, in some cases it could lead to a waste of cluster resources, for example an application could require significant CPU during its startup, later on allocated resources are not required anymore and it makes sense to optimize CPU in such case and lower CPU limit. I think Kubernetes doesn't provide a support for such scenario as of today, I am wondering if there is any workaround to address this issue, the CPU manager relies on [CFS](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/scheduler/sched-bwc.html), technically wouldn't be possible to modify system configuration (`cpu.cfs_quota_us` for instance), dynamically after pod creation by Kubernetes using initial CPU limits?

Comment: This is not possible right now but there is a proposal for an enhancement of this nature you can review [enhancements/keps/sig-node/1287-in-place-update-pod-resources/](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/tree/master/keps/sig-node/1287-in-place-update-pod-resources)

Answer (score 2):

You can use VerticalPodAutoscaler to achieve this. You'll need to define a CustomResource for this that details which pods to target and the policy to use:
example:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling.k8s.io/v1
kind: VerticalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: my-app-vpa
spec:
  targetRef:
    apiVersion: "apps/v1"
    kind:       Deployment
    name:       my-app
  updatePolicy:
    updateMode: "Auto"
```

More details on installing and using VPA: https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately VPA doesn't solve my issue which is mainly related to a startup burst in CPU consumption, it has to destroy the pod and recreate it to vertically autoscale it, which means either CPU will be throttled or set with a large value during startup, I am looking for a dynamic way to adjust CPU limit without recreating the pod.

Comment: Any luck here @RafikELYAAGOUBI? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Answer (score 1):

This [post](https://partners-intl.aliyun.com/help/en/doc-detail/197267.htm) seems to give the solution or resetting the cpu limits without restarting the POD.

There is also a [MultiDimentionalAutoScaler](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/multidimensional-pod-autoscaling) which seems to be very versatile and can handle a lot of cases that you may need to utilize

Answer (score 1):

[Kubernetes 1.27](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.27.md) introduced [Container Resize Policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/resize-container-resources/#container-resize-policies), which allows specifying the pod's behavior while patching the limits. For example:

```yaml
spec:
  containers:
  - name: demo
    image: nginx
# ...
    resizePolicy:
    - resourceName: cpu
      restartPolicy: NotRequired
    - resourceName: memory
      restartPolicy: RestartContainer
```

Since (at the time of writing this answer) this feature is still in alpha state, it may not be yet available on your k8s provider.